# How to make that when the mouse is enter a usercontrol the control will move to another location?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do that when i move the mouse ENTER to the control it will move the control to the center of the form1.
When i leave the area of the control in it's new location i want it to back to where it was in the original location.

```
private void zedGraphControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            zedGraphControl1.Location = new Point(Width / 2 - zedGraphControl1.Width / 2, Height / 2 - zedGraphControl1.Height / 2);
        } 

private void zedGraphControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            zedGraphControl1.Location = new Point(12,400);
        }
```

The problem is when i move the mouse over the control i see the control also on 12,400 and also in the cneter of form1 and both are blinking very fast.

Comment: This sounds horribly unusable. When the user tries to move the mouse over the control, the control will jump away from them? Better polish your uninstaller, it will get a lot of use.

Comment: I believe we wrote a similar joke program back in high school.

Comment: Of course it is blinking really fast, as soon as your mouse enters the control it jumps to the center of the screen removing the mouse from the control which in turns causes it to jump back... rinse and repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you forget to put a validations in your code. Also refreshing and invalidating your Form1 to force redrawing the user control. I also override the user controls virtual methods OnMouseLeave() and OnMouseEnter() to tell them redraw the host usercontrol.

Try modifying your code in this

```
        private void zedGraphControl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.Location == new Point(12, 400))
                this.Location = new Point(Width / 2 - this.Width / 2, Height / 2 - this.Height / 2);
        }

        private void zedGraphControl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Location == new Point(Width / 2 - this.Width / 2, Height / 2 - this.Height / 2))
                this.Location = new Point(12, 400);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            this.Invalidate();
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        }
```

I tested this and it works. Hope it helps.